# How to record the number of times a button is clicked in my code?

Tags: java, android

I want to record the number of times a certain button is clicked in the android studio and then display it and the time it was clicked when another button is pressed.

Comment: This can be solved by writing some code.

Comment: You may want this but it isn't gonna fly. You already know that your post will need to show at least some sort of effort. Show use what you've tried and where you think your having difficulty. I and everyone else in SO want this.

Answer (score 0):

create one integer variable and every button click increment that variable like below:

```
    int i=0;

    buttonname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override       public void onClick(View view) 
        { 
           i++;    
        }   
 });
 textview.setText(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

take one variable for each button and assign 0 value then each button click that variable value increment.

```
    var i=0
    mBtnClick=findViewById(R.id.count)
    mBtnClick?.setOnClickListener {
        textview?.text = ""+i++
    }
```